# How do I convert .txt file to a list in python?

Tags: python

I have a file called movies.txt and it contains a list of 1000 different movie titles. E.g

```
A Nous la Liberte (1932)    
About Schmidt (2002)    
Absence of Malice (1981)    
Adam's Rib (1949)   
....
....
```

I would like to extract these movie titles in the .txt file and add them to a list in my python program but I am getting a type error. Here is my code.

Note: `"File name: "` input is `'movies.txt'`.

```
file = open((input("File name: ")), "r")
movies_list = file.readlines()
movies_list = [movie.strip() for movie in movies_list]
file.close()
print(movies_list[0,1])
```

This is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/liamemery/PycharmProjects/assignmenttwo/QuestionTwo.py", line 40, in <module>
    load()
  File "/Users/liamemery/PycharmProjects/assignmenttwo/QuestionTwo.py", line 6, in load
    print(movies_list[0,1])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: `movies_list[0:1]` or `movies_list[0], movies_list[1]` would get you expected results.

Comment: Why did you specify movies_list[0, 1] in print statement?

Comment: What is `movies_list[0,1]` supposed to mean? What do you want to print?

Comment: I want to print the first two items of the list to test it is working

Comment: Oh wow, what a basic mistake, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem appears to be only with displaying the results.
When selecting from a list, you can either select a certain index, e.g.:

```
print movies_list[0]
```

or a range, e.g.:

```
print movies_list[0:3]
print movies_list[3:-1]
```

or you can print the entire list:

```
print movies_list
```

You can't use commas in the square brackets for lists.

Answer (score 1):

For printing the first two items you may use list slicing as :

```
lst[:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement is wrong `print(movies_list[0,1])`.
print either the whole list or one item

`print(movies_list)` or `print(movies_list[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Index with integer as 0, 1, 2, and so on

```
print movies_list[0] # A Nous la Liberte (1932)   
print movies_list[1] # About Schmidt (2002)
```